# Prove that if $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a}$, then $f$ has a limit at a.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that if $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a}$, then $f$ has a limit at a.

I have written a very basic level proof here:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want $\delta > 0$ such that $|(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}) - (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}})| < \epsilon$ whenever $0<|x - a|<\delta$. So for $\delta = g(\epsilon)$, $0<|x - a|<\delta \implies |(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}) - (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}})| < \epsilon$.

I tried and failed to find a way to represent delta in terms of epsilon. Saying, $\delta = g(\epsilon)$, is wrong. I saw some examples where they set $\delta=1$ and the used the $min$ function. I tried this but was not successful.

Edit: I need to find an answer using the epsilon-delta form. just solving for the limit is not sufficient.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: False if $a=0.$

Comment: This is equivalent to proving that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable, which is only true for *positive* $x$. So you need to assume $a>0$.

Comment: Why are you trying $|\frac 1{\sqrt x - \sqrt a} - L|$ when the limit is supposed to be of $\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{x-a}$? If $x \ne a$ then $\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{x-a} = \frac 1{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}$; not $\frac 1{\sqrt x - \sqrt a}$

Comment: I think that was just a typo. My fault

Comment: Why don't you allow limits of continuous functions.  If $x \ne a$ then $\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{x-a} = \frac 1{\sqrt x +\sqrt a}$.  And $\lim_{x\to a} (\sqrt x + \sqrt a) = 2\sqrt a$ so $\lim_{x\to a}\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt a}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac 1{\sqrt x +\sqrt a}=\frac 1{\lim_{x\to a} (\sqrt x + \sqrt a)} = \frac 1{2\sqrt a}$.  That's legit, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinR I don't think it is a duplicate since the OP here is specifically about $\epsilon-\delta $ proof. I'm going to reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that for $a> 0$

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a}= \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a} \frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}=$$

$$=\frac{x-a}{(x-a)(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}} \to \frac1{2\sqrt a}$$

As an alternative assuming wlog $|x-a|<\frac a 2$

$$ \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a}-\frac1{2\sqrt a}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}-\frac1{2\sqrt a}\right|=\left|\frac{2\sqrt a-\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{2\sqrt a(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a})}\right|=$$

$$=|x-a|\left|\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt{x} }{2\sqrt a(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a})(x-a)}\right|<|x-a|\left|\frac{\sqrt a }{2\sqrt a(3 \sqrt{a})\frac a 2}\right|=\frac{|x-a|}{3a^\frac32}$$

therefore assuming $\delta=3\epsilon a^\frac32$ we have

$$ \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}{x-a}-\frac1{2\sqrt a}\right|<\frac{|x-a|}{3a^\frac32}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Very very good your answers.

Comment: This is what I had at first but I was told we needed it in the epsilon delta form.

Comment: @GoHawkeyes Ah ok, I try to add also something with that method.

Answer (score 4):

$x,a >0$.

$\epsilon >0$ be given.

$\left|\dfrac{\sqrt x-\sqrt a}{(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)(\sqrt x-\sqrt a)}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt a}\right|=$

$\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x+\sqrt a}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt a}\right|=$

$\left|\dfrac{\sqrt a-\sqrt x}{2\sqrt a(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)}\right|=$

$\dfrac{\left|x-a\right|}{2\sqrt a(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)^2}<$

$\dfrac{\left|x-a\right|}{a^{3/2}}.$

Choose $\delta=\epsilon a^{3/2}$;

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful!

Comment: GoHawkeyes.A pleasure:)

Comment: User.Thanks for editing.